# Import sw parts to blender

Tags: import, file-format

How can I import SW part to blender? 
It says VRML and python code, I can't import it that way. I am using blender 2.74
How to proceed?

Comment: it's worth taking a few minutes to bookmark and read the manual: http://www.blender.org/manual/physics/particles/physics/introduction.html

Comment: I think the question is short, but a meaningful text-based answer would be a couple of paragraphs. You might want to visit this thread [Custom-Build-Blender-Fracture-Modifier](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?343637-Custom-Build-Blender-Fracture-Modifier) which deals with a more experimental feature of Blender (breaking stuff) . But i'm not sure how easy it is to virtually grind geometry to powder. Worth reading that and asking there, if this gets closed as a tutorial request here.

Comment: our problem with this question is that it is really 3 or 4 questions. - how to import from SW, how to make a particle simulation - how to export to SW. If you focus on 3 questions separately (You may ask as many Unique questions as you want) then you are more likely to get help. Please limit your questions to one topic at a time. That way the question will have a good title and be easy to find for other people.

Comment: We have about 10.000 questions on this site, if you add 3 more that's no problem :)

Comment: VRML is a dead format, try `.obj`

Comment: it gives error on SW, i tired with >VRML converted from 1.0 to 97 and i added my part in blender but it is very small, any other format to advice me?

Comment: you can rescale an object after the import, select it, press `S`, then hit `3`, followed by `Enter` it will scale it 3 times

Comment: thanks, how can i make the keypad arows to change the view , like panning?

Comment: this comments section is not for asking new questions, please ask a fresh one.